# US states in abbreviated form in Shopify

Tags: api, shopify

During checkout, US states are currently spelled out in Shopify once selected.

Is it possible to display it once selected to abbreviated form?
We would like to be able to export this information in abbreviated form.

Answer (score 0):

The checkout text is not editable.

If you're really keen on having the abbreviated version in the exported data, you could do some post-processing to find instances of the long names and replace them with the abbreviations.